# insert in unordered_set a new element: should the hint be end()?

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

If I am sure that a certain value is not yet into an `unordered_set`, and I am going to insert such value, is it correct to pass this set `end()` iterator as a hint?

EDIT:

Code:

```
#include <unordered_set>
using namespace std;

unordered_set<int> someset;

int main(){
    auto it=someset.find(0);
    if(it==someset.end()) someset.insert(it, 0);    //correct? possible performance boost if the set is actually populated?
}
```

Comment: Show some code eexample to illustrate what you mean.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think, you can simply call `insert` function and the returned value will tell you whether value is inserted, or it is already present in the set.

```
auto p = someset.insert(value);
if (!p.second) 
{
   std::cout << "value was already present in the set" << std::endl;
}
```

Actually `p` is of type `std::pair<iterator,bool>`, so `p.second` tells you whether value is inserted, or it is already present in the set, and `p.first` is the iterator which tells you the position of the value.

Remember that this is faster than your approach, because my solution reduces the overall work.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are referring to `iterator insert ( const_iterator hint, value_type&& val );` which is a member of C++11's `unordered_set`. As described [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/unordered_set/insert/) the `hint` is used for performance optimization when inserting new elements. The insertion / position of the new element is based on hashes. So if you know how the hash is generated for your `value_type` you can pre-generate it and give a hint to the container.

However, the compiler may decide not to use it. So my hypothesis is: using `end()` may be used  but it may not have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

I believe **the hint is of no use** to `unordered_set`, the same way it is of no use to `unordered_map`. These methods exist to maintain these containers' interface compatible with their ordered versions (`set` and `map`, respectively).

Read more here: [std::unordered_map insert with hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559655/stdunordered-map-insert-with-hint)