# Insert or update key in nested unordered map

Tags: c++, nested, unordered-map

I'm trying to update a key in a nested map if it exists or insert it if it doesn't. I'm trying to use an iterator with lower_bound to make this process efficient.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>> maps;
cache::iterator iter(maps[command[1]].lower_bound(command[2]));
if (iter == maps[command[1]].end() || command[2] < iter->first) {
  maps[command[1]].insert(iter, std::make_pair(command[2], command[3]));
} else {
  iter->second = command[3];
}
```

I'm getting the following compile time error:
`no member named 'lower_bound' in 'std::unordered_map<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>, std::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > > >'`

Comment: That's because [`std::unordered_map::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) doesn't exist! It doesn't make sense to look for a lower bound on a container where the elements aren't sorted.

Comment: So is there no efficient way to solve this?

Comment: What is wrong with using `find` to see if the element exists?

Comment: An insert hint is not really useful on a hash-based container (unless the new element hashes to the same as the element pointed to by the hint, which would basically mean it is the same element, in which case you wouldn't be inserting anyway).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15559655

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name suggests, `unordered_map` is not ordered in any particular way. Because `lower_bound` methods and functions refer to the order of elements, they make sense only on ordered data. That's why there is no such method for `unordered_map`.

Many benchmarks on many compilers have shown that an  `std::map`, with fewer that a thousand elements, is significantly faster than `std::unordered_map`. This means that you should consider switching to an `std::map`, or use the following:

```
maps[command[1]].insert_or_assign(command[2], command[3]);
```