# std::unordered_map how to optimize bulk insert if input size is known

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization, stl, unordered-map

If I know I'm going to insert large amount of data (about one million entries) into `std::unordered_map`, is there anything I can do in advance to boost the performance? (just like `std::vector::reserve` can reserve enough memory space to avoid reallocate when I roughly know the size of data before bulk insert)

More specifically, the key in hashmap is a coordinate in 2D plane with customized hash function, as shown below

```
using CellIndex = std::pair<int32_t, int32_t>;

struct IdxHash {
  std::size_t operator()(const std::pair<int32_t, int32_t> &idx) const { return ((size_t)idx.second << 31) ^ idx.first; }
};

std::unordered_map<CellIndex, double, IdxHash> my_map;

// bluk insert into my_map
...
```

Comment: Did you try `std::unordered_map::reserve()` ?

Comment: the document said `std::unordered_map::reserve()` will reserve bucket nums. I think this might be somehow different from the number of entries, and I'm not pretty sure what's the best strategy for it, I'm still tuning with different numbers.

Comment: `Sets the number of buckets to the number needed to accommodate at least count elements without exceeding maximum load factor and rehashes the container.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::unordered_map` is typically implemented as a *chained hash table with linked lists*. As such, inserting into an `std::unordered_map` takes constant time on average, and linear time in the size of the container in the worst case. This worst-case scenario for insertion corresponds to the case when the hash table elements must be *rehashed* because the current number of buckets in the table is insufficient to satisfy the [*load factor*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/load_factor), and, therefore, a reallocation of the array of buckets is needed.

Keeping this in mind, if you know in advance the number of elements to insert into the `std::unordered_map`, you should consider [`std::unordered_map::reserve()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/reserve) to prevent rehashing from happening at insertion. This way, you will avoid both the bucket array reallocation and the rehashing from occurring.

#### [`std::unordered_map::insert()` with *hint*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15559655/8012646)

As with `std::map`, there are some overloads of the [`insert()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) member function that take a so called *hint*:

```
iterator insert(const_iterator hint, const value_type& value);
```

This hint iterator may be used to provide some additional information that can be used to speed the insertion up. However, the existence of these member functions in `std::unordered_map` taking a hint is only for interface compatibility reasons, to make its interface more suitable for generic programming. So, they don't improve the insertion time.

#### About the hash function

How perfect your hash function is shouldn't really matter when it comes to insertion time – only how fast it calculates the hash of a key. However, it becomes relevant when looking up elements in the hash table by their keys.

Answer (score 0):

`reserve(x)` prepares the unordered container for `x` number of elements. In comparison `rehash(x)` prepares the unordered container for `x/max_load_factor()` number of elements.

Also regarding your hash function, if you're aiming for it to return a unique value for a pair of coordinates, then it should return `((size_t)idx.second << 32) ^ idx.first`. `((size_t)idx.second << 31) ^ idx.first` will return the same value for `(1, -1)` and `(0, 2^31-1)`.

Comment: Should probably use `|` instead of `^`. It took me a moment to realise that they're actually the same in this case.